# Transversal Matroid

Tags: co.combinatorics

I am trying to figure out why the transversal matroid is a matroid.
Specifically, if $L$ and $M$ are two independent sets s.t. $|L| < |M|$, why is there an $i$ in $M \setminus L$ s.t. $L \cup \{ i \} $ is independent?
thank you in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me check that we have the same definition of transversal matroids. For me, the input is a bipartite graph $\Gamma$, with white vertex set $W$ and black vertex set $B$. The ground set of the matroid is $B$, with a subset of $B$ being independent if it can be matched to a subset of $W$.

**Direct Proof that this is a matroid:** Suppose that $M$ and $L$ are subsets of $B$ can be matched, with $|L|<|M|$. Superimpose the matchings. 
This gives a graph $G$ where the elements each vertex has degree $\leq 2$ -- so a union of paths and cycles (including possibly some $2$ cycles.) We'll call an edge of $G$ *mauve* or *lavender* acording to whether it comes from $M$ or $L$. In each path or cycle of $G$, the edges alternate color.

Each element of $M \setminus L$ gives a degree $1$ in $B$ at the end of a mauve edge, and each element of $L \setminus M$ gives a degree one element of $B$ at the end of a lavender edge. Since $|M| > |L|$, there must be a path one of whose ends is a mauve edge ending in $W$ and whose other end is *not* a lavender edge ending in $B$. The only other possibility for the end of that path is a mauve edge ending in $W$. In other words, this path has vertices $b_1$, $w_1$, $b_2$, $w_2$, ..., $b_r$, $w_r$ where $b_i$ is matched to $w_i$ in $M$,  $w_i$ is matched to $b_{i+1}$ in $L$ and $b_1$ and $w_r$ are not matched in $L$. Now modify $L$ to match $b_i$ to $w_i$, leaving all other elements of $L$ matched as before. This is a matching of $L \cup \{ b_1 \}$.

**Conceptual proof** Take a matrix $A$ with rows labeled by $W$ and columns labeled by $B$. Place a $0$ in $A_{bw}$ if $\Gamma$ has no edge between $b$ and $w$, and place algebraically independent elements in the positions where $\Gamma$ does have an edge. The transversal matroid is realized by the columns of this matrix.

Comment: thank you very much!
I acctually reffered to the Transversal matroid presented here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gammoid#Transversal_matroids
but your version is the same (if the black side are the sets A_i, the white side is the elements of E and there is an edge if the element is in A_i.

Comment: Among its other virtues, the conceptual proof is better because it shows that the matroid is not only a matroid, but is representable (assuming the field is large enough for the relevant scheme to have rational points).

Comment: Just curious how the proof of exchange property of matching matroids is different from this argument? I'm thinking they are the same.